# Error in launching application on phone simulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been having an error with launching my `flutter` application on my iPhone simulator.

This is what I am getting.

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode... Running
> Xcode build...                                                   Xcode
> build done.                                           37.1s Failed to
> build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
> --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder,
> name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FFE237E1-BEF3-4A5C-BDC0-8453BFFAC939, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2D32F1A7-D208-48FD-98C3-F1127400EFDE, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1036C004-B947-4D58-96DE-FA2DD13D1DC8, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A9CD97D7-CB15-4CA1-9039-E61C083E86D3, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2E55A7CA-677C-4429-9415-AFCA8AB524AA, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3A3DB989-EF02-45B4-83E1-7097FA10E9D6, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0ADEE93E-6C28-4A92-9F3D-031F5AFD6B48, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F4AF895C-BCA2-4EA2-BAFC-3D3E8228539A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A3FE3EFB-8F4C-445D-93C8-6738D5A0DC16, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:083266D8-8D3F-44E1-8005-EAF72B1DA4B5, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8B5025D4-3D5E-42FA-BCB2-1DEE4BEF7AC1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:56FCECF1-A09A-43B2-9764-75AE78CF9321, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:62AC8F9B-A87A-4065-AC6C-E8307E1A67A6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C27F8D24-398F-4441-A824-152E08E31D01, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7D11D52D-77CA-439D-B529-A05A7052BB8D, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5E1AC482-4D85-46AA-985B-8CAE96CCD8CC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A2050C1-625D-4490-9251-6F9BB506BF03, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:32EFD7A1-7FA5-4797-BEC8-1573863BB7AA, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5711B054-53C3-479F-8974-B3029BFDBFF4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:916A9E01-E3B5-4403-A071-F10655E391AD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
> { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4CC4B513-EEDC-4F19-A8F2-C4B1E08EF841, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
> { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS
> Device }
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

```
 - package:font_awesome_flutter
 - package:flutter_icons
 - package:carousel_slider

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
Failed to package /Users/roseanne/test_app.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select
a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Answer (score 0):

It's a error related to the flutter [null safety](https://docs.flutter.dev/null-safety), some of the packages that you imported don't have a null safety compatibility.

If you update (or remove if they don't have a null safe version) the packages listed bellow, it should be working fine.

```
 - package:font_awesome_flutter
 - package:flutter_icons
 - package:carousel_slider
```